# Explaining difference between Sky View Factor and its simplified version in SAGA's algorithm

Tags: qgis, saga

I calculated the Sky View Factor using SAGA's algorithm. It generates different outputs: [Module Sky View Factor](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.0/ta_lighting_3.html).

However, I could not find the difference between the outpus, especially among 'Visible sky', 'Sky View Factor' and 'Sky View Factor (simplified)'.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the *sky view factor* and the *visible sky* is explained by a saga developer [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/790705/thread/4637cde9/):

> The "visible sky" describes the percentage of the unobstructed hemisphere above a certain location.

> The "sky view factor" varies from 1 for completely unobstructed land surface (like horizontal surfaces or peaks and ridges) to 0 for completely obstructed land surface.

However, I don't know what the difference is between the *sky view facto*r and the *simplified sky view factor*.